# Past value in vba

Tags: excel, copy-paste, vba

I am trying to select the column that contains SUM formula. and I want to copy the formula and past only the value in the same column. but this code does not change the formula into the value. any idea how i could solve this?

```
Sub Registrereren()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next

Dim oWkSht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim c As Date
Dim myCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("Registration").Activate


Set oWkSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
LastColumn = oWkSht.Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
LastRow = oWkSht.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

c = Date

Set myCell = oWkSht.Range("1:1").Find(What:=c, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

If Not myCell Is Nothing Then
    myCell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=New_Order!N2+New_Order!O2+New_Order!P2"
    Range(myCell.Offset(1), Cells(LastRow, myCell.Column)).Select
    Selection.FillDown

    Range(myCell.Offset(1), LastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range(myCell.Offset(1), LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

Sheets("Main").Activate

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. LastRow is not a valid range as it is only a row number.

```
Sub Registrereren()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim oWkSht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim c As Date
Dim myCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set oWkSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Registration")
LastColumn = oWkSht.Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
LastRow = oWkSht.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

c = Date

Set myCell = oWkSht.Range("1:1").Find(What:=c, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

If Not myCell Is Nothing Then
    With oWkSht.Range(myCell.Offset(1), oWkSht.Cells(LastRow, myCell.Column))
        .Formula = "=New_Order!N2+New_Order!O2+New_Order!P2"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End If

Sheets("Main").Activate

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you